# Does Chromium use less RAM than Chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, chromium, ram

As I know Chrome is a memory hog, I would like to know if Chromium in Ubuntu has less memory usage than Chrome, as I'm running Ubuntu on a HP Pavilion with 4GB RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chromium and Chrome are (usually) on par for memory usage with the caveat that Chromium can sometimes be just a step or two ahead of Google Chrome. This is due to Google Chrome being based off of the Chromium browser so any changes upstream (from Chromium) have to be integrated with the existing Google Chrome codebase.

That being said, Chrome can become heavier in some use cases where heavy tracking is enabled.

Comment: Thanks! Today I just used Chromium, it's really buggy. Whereas Chrome is more faster. Anyways Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to mark this problem as solved.